# Pynput not updating mouse.position on Mac

Tags: python, pynput

I'm fiddling around with pynput for a personal project, and can't seem to get it working properly. It works perfectly with listening for keyboard and mouse input, but when I try update the mouse position to move it, nothing happens. This is the code I'm currently using to test it:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller, Listener

mouse = Controller()


class Mover:
    def __init__(self, original_position=mouse.position):
        self.original_position = original_position

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == Button.left:
            self.original_position = mouse.position  # remember the position
            print(mouse.position)

        else:
            mouse.position = self.original_position  # return to position
            print(mouse.position)
            return False


mover = Mover()

with Listener(
        on_click=mover.on_click
) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I'm running MacOS Monterey. Any help is much appreciated.

When running the above code, it prints out the mouse position as expected, but when right clicking, the mouse position does not update to original_position.

Comment: A few questions: are you running your script as root/`sudo`? Have you whitelisted your package or entire Python installation under *Enable access for assistive devices* in System Preferences (plus Terminal, since you're running on Mojave or later)? See [Platform limitations::macOS](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#macos)

Comment: @esqew Thank you so much, I was running as sudo, and I thought I'd whitelisted Python, but clearly I wasn't paying attention when doing so, because I went back to verify it and realised I'd only whitelisted the python launcher. I whitelisted my python installation now and everything's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [`pynput`'s page on Platform Limitations#macOS](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html#macos):

> Recent versions of macOS restrict monitoring of the keyboard for
> security reasons. For that reason, one of the following must be true:
>
> - The process must run as root.
> - Your application must be white listed under *Enable access for assistive devices*. Note that this might require that you package your
>   application, since otherwise the entire Python installation must be
>   white listed.
> - On versions after Mojave, you may also need to whitelist your terminal application if running your script from a terminal.

Per comments on the OP, the Python kernel was not whitelisted in System Preferences' *Enable access for assistive devices* section. Doing so resolved the reported issue.